# Bootstrap issue when using select 2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 for typeahead. The functionaity works fine but it distorts my input fields.

For example this code

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">Search for a Property</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- County Column -->
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <select class ="form-control" id="county" name="county">
              <!--Gets all counties from DB -->
              <option> - Select a County - </option>
              @foreach ($county as $counties)
                <option>{{$counties->name}}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <select class="town form-control" name="town">
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  $('.town').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select an item',
    ajax: {
      url: '/townsearch',
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results:  $.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    text: item.name,
                    id: item.name
                }})};},
      cache: true
    }});
</script>
```

Will produce the following

[Image of two dropdowns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhX1U.png)

Dropdown 1 is the way I want it. Dropdown 2 is the effect of select2. Any fixes?

Comment: Anyone??????????

Comment: Does the console give you some more information? Some errors maybe?

Comment: No errors which is weird